z/OS zero length side deck file generated, no warnings displayed
I'm trying to compile an executable on z/OS.  The final step fails with a handful of undefined symbols.  Presumably this is because the step before it that is generating a .so also generates a zero length .x file.  The .so looks sane, Executing 'nm' on it shows the missing symbols as being defined.
A typical .o was compiled with
xlclang -c -m64 -fvisibility=default -DOS390 -DZOS -D_EXT=1 -D_ALL_SOURCE -Duserelocatableinc -DMAXSIG=39 -DNSIG=39 -DOEMVS -DYYDYNAMIC -DNO_LOCALE_MESSAGES -D_OPEN_THREADS=3 -D_UNIX03_SOURCE=1 -D_AE_BIMODAL=1 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -D_ALL_SOURCE -D_ENHANCED_ASCII_EXT=0xFFFFFFFF -D_OPEN_SYS_FILE_EXT=1 -D_OPEN_SYS_SOCK_IPV6 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -D_SHR_ENVIRON -DNO_NL_LOCALE_NAME -DDEBUGGING -g -c -m64 util.c 

The step that is yielding the zero length .x looks like
clang -o libperl.so -shared -Wl,-bedit=no -m64 op.o perl.o universal.o av.o builtin.o caretx.o class.o  deb.o doio.o doop.o dquote.o  dump.o globals.o gv.o hv.o  keywords.o locale.o mathoms.o mg.o  mro_core.o numeric.o pad.o peep.o  perlio.o perly.o pp.o pp_ctl.o  pp_hot.o pp_pack.o pp_sort.o pp_sys.o  reentr.o regcomp.o regcomp_debug.o regcomp_invlist.o regcomp_study.o regcomp_trie.o  regexec.o run.o scope.o sv.o  taint.o time64.o toke.o utf8.o  util.o   os390.o /karlw/zopen/usr/local/zopen/zoslib/zoslib/lib/libzoslib.x DynaLoader.o -lm -lc 

Any advice, including further debugging steps I could take, would be appreciated

Are you trying to compile perl? Have you read https://perldoc.perl.org/perlos390 ?

Yes, and I am one of the authors of that document

Usually you don’t want to mix different compilers. You have xlclang and clang which are different compilers. In this case it can work, but you do need to make sure you export whichever functions or data you want as part of your side deck. Did you specify something like the -qexportall option for the initial compilation?
For example, here is a simple setup that works. You can try a simple source and compile command set as well and then build up to your existing compilation commands.
---funcs.c---
int fool1(int val1) {
  return val1 * 11;
}

int passCode(void) {
  return 5;
}

int checkTheCode(int code) {
  return code == 55;
}

int main(void) {
  if (checkTheCode(foo11(passCode()))) {
    return foo11(passCode());
  } else {
    return fool1(6);
  }
}


xlclang funcs.c -c -m64 -fvisibility=default -qexportall
clang -o funcs.so --shared -Wl,-bedit=no -m64 funcs.o
That should give you the following:
--- funcs.x ---
IMPORT CODE64,'funcs.so','checkTheCode'
IMPORT CODE64,'funcs.so','fool1'
IMPORT CODE64,'funcs.so','passCode' 


Hope this helps
z/OS XL C/C++ Compiler Dev

It does seem like a bad idea to use two compilers; I ended up trying with xlclang all the way.  The documentation for it from ibm yields a broken link, so all I had was the output of --help.  It does not mention -m64 nor -shared nor -fvisibility, and bedit seems like it is for a different purpose.  Now I get to the same place, and no .x file is generated at all  A typical compilation command looks like

xlclang -c -DPERL_CORE -std=c99 -D_EXT -Wc,lp64 -qexportall -qfloat=ieee -DOS390 -DZOS -D_ALL_SOURCE -DMAXSIG=39 -DNSIG=39 -DOEMVS -DYYDYNAMIC -DNO_LOCALE_MESSAGES -D_OPEN_THREADS=3 -D_UNIX03_SOURCE=1 -D_AE_BIMODAL=1 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -D_ALL_SOURCE -D_ENHANCED_ASCII_EXT=0xFFFFFFFF -D_OPEN_SYS_FILE_EXT=1 -D_OPEN_SYS_SOCK_IPV6 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED -D_EXT -D_SHR_ENVIRON -DDEBUGGING -g -c -std=c99 -D_EXT -Wc,lp64 -Wl,lp64 -qexportall os390.c

And the .so generation step is xlclang -o libperl.so -Wl,lp64 op.o perl.o universal.o av.o builtin.o caretx    .o class.o  deb.o doio.o doop.o dquote.o  dump.o globals.o gv.o hv.o  keywor    ds.o locale.o mathoms.o mg.o  mro_core.o numeric.o pad.o peep.o  perlio.o pe    rly.o pp.o pp_ctl.o  pp_hot.o pp_pack.o pp_sort.o pp_sys.o  reentr.o regcomp    .o regcomp_debug.o  regcomp_invlist.o regcomp_study.o regcomp_trie.o  regexe    c.o run.o scope.o sv.o  taint.o time64.o toke.o utf8.o  util.o   os390.o Dyn    aLoader.o -lm -lc

which yields IEW2689W 4C40 DEFINITION SIDE FILE IS NOT DEFINED.
FSUM3065 The LINKEDIT step ended with return code 4.  but a .so is generated.  The final load fails with missing symbols that are in the .so

Using just xlclang the bind command would be:
xlclang -o funcs.so -Wl,dll -q64 funcs.o
The xlclang invocation command uses the same binder (-Wl,dll) and compiler+binder options (-q64) as the XL compiler.
There is no need for -lm or -lc as the C library is always a part of the application on z/OS.
Hope this helps.
